# autoload_paths not aware of namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.3

In `app/services`, I have some classes, as `Notification::Finder` and `Notification::Builder`.

They are placed as `app/services/notification/builder.rb` and `app/services/notification/finder.rb`.

There is also the `Notification` class as a model, at `app/models/notification.rb`

The autoload_path is configurated as in `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/services)`

When I try to load `Finder`, it works:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.9)
[1] pry(main)> Notification::Finder
=> Notification::Finder
```

But when I try the `Builder`, I get a problem with the rails autoloading:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.9)
[1] pry(main)> Notification::Builder
=> ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder
```

It just ignores the namespace I've used when the constant name (Builder) has already been defined by other namespace, and gets the `ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder` instead.

**Is this the expected behavior, or a rails bug?**

Going more detailed, the `const_missing` method at `activesupport/dependencies.rb` receives a `const_name 'Builder'`, and `nesting.inspect => 'nil'`.

Curious that when I use constantize, it resolves as expected:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.9)
[1] pry(main)> 'Notification::Builder'.constantize
=> Notification::Builder
```

( Rails issue at github: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8726 )

Comment: Is it possible that `Builder` is a reserved name?

Comment: can you reproduce it in a fresh application? If so, please put one up on github and let me know. I'll take a look. There are situations where the rails autoloader will not be able to return the right result. I think this one should be possible though...

Comment: @YvesSenn, thanks for the help :D I've put a simpler version of the error here: https://github.com/rodrigues/autoload_zomg

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder is a module in Rails. If you have a Notification::Builder, you can ask it its class:

```
>> Notification::Builder
=> ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder
>> Notification::Builder.class
=> Module
>> Notification::Builder.ancestors
=> [ActiveRecord::Associations::Builder]
```

> Is this expected behavior?

Yes

> OK, so... what choices do you have?

- You can use a different term than Builder. Like Factory. or Notification::NotificationBuilder

More info:
* http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/Builder/Association
* http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/Builder

Answer (score 1):

This problem exists because you are using an ActiveRecord model as a namespace. I created a gist with some experimentation until I saw the root cause.

`ActiveRecord` models include the `ActiveRecord::Associations` module. Since you can get to a constant when including a module the `Builder` constant defined within `Associations` is now also reachable through the AR model. You will get this behavior with every class defined in the modules, which are included into an AR model:

```
1.9.3-p194 :010 > Post.ancestors
 => [Post(id: integer, title: string, published_at: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime), Post::GeneratedFeatureMethods, #<Module:0x007fec74dc33a0>, ActiveRecord::Base, ActiveRecord::Core, ActiveRecord::Store, ActiveRecord::Serialization, ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml, ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON, ActiveModel::Serialization, ActiveRecord::Reflection, ActiveRecord::Transactions, ActiveRecord::Aggregations, ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes, ActiveRecord::AutosaveAssociation, ActiveModel::SecurePassword, ActiveRecord::Associations, ActiveRecord::Timestamp, ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks, ActiveRecord::Callbacks, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Dirty, ActiveModel::Dirty, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::PrimaryKey, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Query, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::BeforeTypeCast, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Write, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Read, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods, ActiveModel::AttributeMethods, ActiveRecord::Locking::Pessimistic, ActiveRecord::Locking::Optimistic, ActiveRecord::CounterCache, ActiveRecord::Validations, ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods, ActiveSupport::Callbacks, ActiveModel::Validations, ActiveRecord::Integration, ActiveModel::Conversion, ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment, ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection, ActiveModel::DeprecatedMassAssignmentSecurity, ActiveRecord::Sanitization, ActiveRecord::Scoping::Named, ActiveRecord::Scoping::Default, ActiveRecord::Scoping, ActiveRecord::Inheritance, ActiveRecord::ModelSchema, ActiveRecord::ReadonlyAttributes, ActiveRecord::Persistence, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Loadable, V8::Conversion::Object, JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

A possible solution is to use a module as a namespace. For example `module Notifications`.